# Launcher Activity and Thread run() is called twice

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app is starting twice and the weird thing is, it depends on the LOAD_TIME which activity is called twice. With a long delay, like >5000ms, my Main Activity is called twice. As you can see in the snap shot, with 2000ms, my startup activity and my run() Thread is called twice.

It also only happens on my emulator, if I use my physical phone everything runs fine. I thought it might has something to do with the Consumer class, which requires a newer build version. But I think it requires 24 and I am using Nexus 5 with version 30 so I should be fine.

Ami doing something wrong with the lifecycle or threading?

```
public class StartUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final int LOAD_TIME = 2000;
    public static int counter;
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        counter++;
        Log.d("debug counter startup: ", counter+"");

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_up);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titel_bar);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("debug Handler: ", "run()");
                PreLogin checkLoginStatus = new PreLogin();
                checkLoginStatus.CheckIfStillLoggedIn((value) -> {
                    if(value==true){
                        Log.d("debug checkLogin", "checkIfStillLoggedIn=true");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(StartUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("caller", "StartUpActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("debug checkLogin", "checkIfStillLoggedIn=false");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(StartUpActivity.this, ChooseLoginOrRegistrationActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("caller", "StartUpActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                handler.removeCallbacks(null);
            }
        }, LOAD_TIME);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".StartUpActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

[image]